# convert sql query in R

Tags: sql, r

i would like to convert the following sql query in R.

i am able to create a connection and run simple queries to extract tables from sql. However the problem is with the insert into query. rather than inserting into the "sb" table in sql database, i want the insert into query to work on a dataframe. basically carry out the exact same action by inserting into a dataframe rather than a sql table.

```
insert into [uk].[dbo].[sb] (
    [treaty_id],
    [period])
select
    [treaty_code],
    [cap_period]
  from 
    [ukdm].[dbo].[rds]
  where
    [cap_period]='2023/09'
```

i know i can split out the select portion and import as below but the problem is for calculated columns which i calculate from the rds table. i specify the column names in the insert into block for such columns in SQL

```
 df <- tbl(con, sql("select
    [treaty_code],
    [cap_period]
from 
    [ukdm].[dbo].[rds]
  where
    [cap_period]='2023/09'"))
```

Comment: You say *"calculated columns"* but I see nothing here that indicates much at all. Why is it not just `%>% filter(cap_period == "2023/09") %>% select(treat_code, cap_period)` and then insert?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for bind_rows() ?

```
df_total <-  df %>% bind_rows(df2)
```

bind_rows will automatically fill the columns with NA's if they are missing in a dataframe.